# Simple thread pool won't buzz

Tags: c++, multithreading

Trying to write a simple thread pool. Only the first `thread_t` is initialized and it sort of hangs. I can't proceed. Need help

```
class thread_t
{
public:
    thread_t(int id, bool& running)
        :id_(id)
        , running_(running)
    {
        idle_ = true;
        thread_ = new thread([=]() { run(); });
    }

    ~thread_t()
    {
        thread_->join();
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        cout << id_ << "  starting  \n";
        while (running_)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10ms));
        }
    }
private:
    thread* thread_;
    bool idle_;
    int id_;
    bool& running_;
};

class pool
{
public:
    pool(int n, bool& running)
        :nthreads_(n)
        ,running_(running)
    {
        if (n > std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) nthreads_ = n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            threads_.push_back(thread_t(i, running_));
        }
    }

private:
    vector<thread_t> threads_;
    int nthreads_;
    bool& running_;
};


//queue < function<void(void)>> tasks;

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    pool pool1(5, running);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5s));

    running = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't edit my query ( class declaration has to be inside code) also, say mostly code, add my text in the queries.

Comment: If this was a Java program, I would say, do not start a thread inside a constructor.  I don't know C++ as well as I know Java, but it seems like you are potentially allowing a `thread_t` object's `run()` method to start using the object before the object has been fully initialized.

Comment: P.S., It _looks_ like your source code assigns all of the object's member variables before it creates the new thread, but in Java land, the new thread does not necessarily see those assignments happen in the same order as the thread that performed them.  So, variables that the first thread thinks were initialized could appear to be uninitialized from the perspective of the new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to join the first thread you created right away.  From `gdb`:

```
#0  0x00007ffff729eb6d in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7ab6223 in __gthread_join (__value_ptr=0x0, 
    __threadid=<optimized out>)
    at /var/tmp/paludis/sys-devel-gcc-7.3.0/work/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:668
#2  std::thread::join (this=0x55555576bc20)
    at /var/tmp/paludis/sys-devel-gcc-7.3.0/work/gcc-7.3.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:136
#3  0x00005555555553ff in thread_t::~thread_t (this=0x7fffffffd6f0, 
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at thread.cpp:21
#4  0x000055555555559b in pool::pool (this=0x7fffffffd740, n=5, 
    running=@0x7fffffffd737: true) at thread.cpp:50
#5  0x0000555555555151 in main () at thread.cpp:66
```

Comment: the threads are supposed to be in a while(true) {} loop in the run() method i.e. they should not terminate, till main signals running = false

Comment: @ark1974 - Whenever you destroy a `thread_t` (and you're destroying the temporary created for `push_back`, you'll try to join.  You'll *also* be destroying `thread_t`s if `push_back` has to resize your vector.

Comment: Yes,  you are right, it is getting destroyed. But why other threads aren't launching ?

Comment: voted: +1 for correcting that pushback was calling the destructor

Comment: @ark1974 - The other threads won't launch if `push_back` has to resize it's internal storage.  During resizing you'll effectively be copying/deleting the current data, and that involves calling `~thread_t` (and by extension, `join`).

Answer (score 0):

Stephen Newwell rightly pointed out that vector::push_back was indeed calling the destructor (+1 to him). Now I use unique_ptr and it solved my issue for now only.

Edited: Just completed this project here's if anybody interested [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189798/simple-versaitile-thread-pool)

```
class thread_t
{
public:
    thread_t(int id, bool& running)
        :id_(id)
        , running_(running)
    {
        idle_ = true;
        thread_ = new thread([=]() { run(); });
    }

    ~thread_t()
    {
        cout << id_ << "  killing  \n";
        thread_->join();
    }

private:
    void run()
    {
        cout << id_ << "  starting  \n";
        while (running_)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10ms));
        }
    }
private:
    thread* thread_;
    bool idle_;
    int id_;
    bool& running_;
};

class pool
{
public:
    pool(int n, bool& running)
        :nthreads_(n)
        ,running_(running)
    {
        if (n > std::thread::hardware_concurrency()) nthreads_ = n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            threads_.push_back(make_unique<thread_t >(i, running_));
        }
    }

private:
    vector<unique_ptr<thread_t>> threads_;
    int nthreads_;
    bool& running_;
};


//queue < function<void(void)>> tasks;

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    pool pool1(5, running);

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(5s));

    running = false;
    return 0;
}
```